# Adobe AIR, HTML/Javascript building digital signage app suitability

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, air, adobe

I have a task to built a simple Digital signage system which will display different kind of information on LCD panels.

I am not sure if Adobe AIR with HTML / Javascript would be a good choice for the desktop part of this application, which will be responsible for displaying the content. The logics could be easily solved and coded in Javascript and the app should run for a long time.

Maybe it would be better to use FLex instead. What do you think?

Thanks for any recommendations.

Comment: Mostly static text + some lines? This can be drawn with pure Flash Graphics API. Speed seems not to be the concern, so why not AIR/Javascript.

Comment: Text, images and probably flv videos. The backend for managing this content will be web based, which is a reason I would like to choose AIR for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, Flash's strong support for animation and graphics manipulation makes it a clear winner for this sort of application. Digital signage apps thrive on features like objects animating around the screen, transparency effects, glows, etc. Flash does all of these things natively.

AIR's HTML + Javascript support basically lets you turn a web app into a native-looking standalone application. It also gives you some additional APIs (e.g. local file access) but other than that, it's pretty much just a captive version of Safari 4 showing content that comes from the hard disk instead of a web server. (Obviously once the AIR app is up and running, it can go off to a web server (or RSS server, or...) to pull more data.)

Safari 4's HTML5 support is strong, but HTML5 is still not as powerful as Flash when it comes to whizzy graphics and animation.

As for Flex, that's pretty much orthogonal to your main question. Flex just gives you a nice application development framework on top of Flash, which is particularly helpful when developing traditional desktop-like applications. Little of what it provides really has anything to do with your digital signage display application.

That's not to say Flex would be useless in this application. You probably also need some kind of data entry and configuration piece. If that's going to be part of the same AIR app that displays the digital signage, the whole thing should probably be built on the Flex framework. If these are two separate pieces, then maybe it makes more sense for the configuration and data entry piece to be Flex-based and for the signage display piece to be purely Flash.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, it really helped me out. I had the same feeling about it but it is good to hear it from someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES.

My company developed a Digital Signage software in 2009 assiciated whith C++ and cloud computing, and we keep using and upgrading this software. ;)
The aministrative panel is PHP, and it has differents levels by user.

Today we are creating a new version in Adobe AIR, but keeping the c++ and cloud server.